# Logback in the Java applet

Tags: java, applet, logback

I'm using logback in the applet and I noted what it sends some strange requests to the server:

[03/Dec/2010 13:09:42] "GET /profiles/alexei/photos/ch/qos/logback/core/AppenderBaseBeanInfo.class/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1827
...
[03/Dec/2010 13:09:42] "GET /profiles/alexei/photos/ch/qos/logback/core/LayoutBaseBeanInfo.class
...
profiles/alexei/photos/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/CyclicBufferTrackerImplBeanInfo.class HTTP/1.1" 302 0
...
etc

How to prevent this? And what is this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but it may be loading the resource via codebase first?

Try disabling: `codebase_lookup`